# Java custom warnings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

Hello I wanted to throw a custom warning. Say i have

```
public abstract class A {

    public void doSomething() {
        //base functionality
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
        //extended functionality
    }
}
public class C extends A {

}
```

i want to throw an error for class C because it does not override the method. Normally an abstract method would suffice but the method contains functionality common to all subclass and if there is a better standard or structure please let me know.

I want to force all subclasses to @Override that certain method

I have looked into creating a custom annotation like 
`public @interface ShouldOverride`
but i could not figure out how to throw a warning with that.

Note. I am using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate

Comment: Why don't you provide for another abstract method that has to be overridden and which is called by `doSomething()`? I wouldn't rely on the IDE to enforce those constraints since one might build the application in a different IDE or on the command line. If you need to enforce those things outside the code itself then try including some static analysis in your build (which is called by all IDEs and executed by command line builds).

Comment: Oh ur right. Why didnt i think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of the proposition of Thomas:

```
abstract class A {

    public void doSomething() {
        // basic things to do

        // then call implementation
        doSomethingImpl();
    }

    protected abstract void doSomethingImpl();
}

class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected void doSomethingImpl() {
        //extended functionality
    }
}

class C extends A {  // does not compile

}
```